# How do I run .cs tests that I normally run in the Visual Studio Test Explorer, in the command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

While I'm developing, I often have to run about 5-6 tests to populate the data I need for tests. I want to automate this so I don't have to right-click/"Run" every time.

How can I get the command that VS is running so that I can just put it into a quick script that runs all the tests I need to run, in a single click (or single command) ?

[image: Visual Studio Test Explorer]

Comment: Create a batch file.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Most have an associated console test running package that can be used to execute tests against the compiled test binaries.

Comment: Also, tangentially related, if you have to run tests in a particular order to set up a state for later tests, you may want to look into your testing framework's equivalent of Setup and TearDown methods to establish the state you're testing, rather than rely on executing them in a particular order.

Comment: I think the testing framework is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: I would rather create a script specifying the tests to run, rather than adding setup and tear down functions, since I don't want to modify the test files themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mstest.exe command line tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Here on stack overflow, you find it under the [mstest] tag, for example [how to run an mstest dll from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946270/how-to-run-an-mstest-dll-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for this tip!

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some links that could help:

https://dev.to/hatsrumandcode/net-core-2-why-xunit-and-not-nunit-or-mstest--aei

https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test